# Improving numerical stability of the Goldstein-Price Function

Tags: function-construction, stability

Goldstein-Price Function is a two-dimensional test function for optimization, defined as $$f(y,z) = \left(\left(3 y^2+2 y (3 z-7)+z (3 z-14)+19\right) (y+z+1)^2+1\right) \times \left(\left(12 y^2-4 y (9 z+8)+3 (z (9 z+16)+6)\right) (2 y-3 z)^2+30\right).$$ It has a global minimum $f(x^*) = 3$ at $x^* = (0,-1)$.

If we look at an implementation of this, for values close enough to the minimum point, the result is smaller than 3.

```
(1+(1+y+z)^2 (19+3 y^2+z (-14+3 z)+2 y (-7+3 z))) (30+(2 y-3 z)^2 (12 
y^2-4 y (8+9 z)+3 (6+z (16+9 z))))/. {y->2.8634789206192827*^-9,z->-1.0000000009997096}
```

The result is show as

```
3.
```

What is the answer really? Well

```
NumberForm[3., 16]
2.999999999999975
```

Thus there is numerical instability. Is there some way to improve the stability?

Comment: To give you some insight: try making a contour plot of your objective function in the vicinity of the minimum.

Comment: Can you explain more why you consider it a problem that the result is less than 3?  There is roundoff error with floating point calculations.  It is completely expected that the result will not be exactly `3`.  The inaccuracy in the result is tiny, merely ~50 ulp.  It's not something I would call instability... Is there any particular significance to the fact that the computed result is smaller and not greater than the exact one?  I don't have much experience in this field.

Comment: You can always use `SetPrecision[{y->2.8634789206192827*^-9,z->-1.0000000009997096}, 20]` to use a higher number of digits for the calculations.